# How can i use the loop without any error in this code?

Tags: haskell, loops

This is a program so that the GHC takes a number n from user and then it forms a list of n numbers which again are given by the user. this code is showing some parse error for loop. How can i remove that error?

```
import System.IO

main = do 
   putStrLn "Please enter the number"
   number <- readLn :: IO Int
   putStrLn $ "The num is:" ++ show number
   loop number
   xs <- sequence [readLn :: IO Int]
   putStrLn xs

loop:: Int -> IO ()
loop n = if 0==n then return () else return loop (n-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what the other answers have said:

You don't need to write a loop function.

```
import System.IO

main = do 
   putStrLn "Please enter the number"
   number <- readLn :: IO Int
   putStrLn $ "The num is:" ++ show number
   xs <- sequence (replicate number (readLn :: IO Int))  -- pay attention to this line
   print xs
```

So we start with `readLn`. `replicate` makes a list of `number` `readLn`s. (Depending on your perspective, you might think this is the clever bit.)

The clever bit: `sequence` takes that list of IO actions, and turns it into one big IO action. Each `readLn` happens in turn, and the return values are collected and returned in a list.

Comment: `sequence . replicate n` ≡ `replicateM n` :)

Comment: @ehird That's true, although `replicateM` isn't in the Prelude, and I feel beginners should understand `sequence` before they learn about trivial functions based on it.

Comment: Huh, I never realised that `sequence` is in the Prelude but `replicateM` isn't. That's strange. But yes, it's probably premature golfing in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are three errors in your code. Copying it and starting it in GHC gives the following messages:

```
temp.hs:9:13
    Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `Int'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: [Int]
    In the first argument of `putStrLn', namely `xs'
    In the expression: putStrLn xs
```

This one is quite clear. `putStrLn` needs a `String`, but `xs` is a list of `Int`s. So simply using `print xs` instead of `putStrLn xs` solves the problem (`print = putStrLn . show`).

The next two are actually about the the same problem:

```
    temp.hs:13:38:
        No instance for (Monad ((->) t0))
          arising from a use of `return'
        Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Monad ((->) t0))
        In the expression: return loop (n - 1)
        In the expression:
          if 0 == n then return () else return loop (n - 1)
        In an equation for `loop':
            loop n = if 0 == n then return () else return loop (n - 1)

temp.hs:13:45:
    Couldn't match expected type `IO ()'
                with actual type `Int -> IO ()'
    In the first argument of `return', namely `loop'
    In the expression: return loop (n - 1)
    In the expression:
      if 0 == n then return () else return loop (n - 1)
```

The problem is in the types. `loop` is of type `Int -> IO ()`. So the first branch of the function is alright, because you `return ()`. However, in the else branch, you return something completely different, because `return` is not some built-in statement of the language, but a normal function. So `return loop (n - 1)` first lifts your `loop` function into the monad and than applies it to `(n - 1)`.

Instead, what you want is:

```
loop n = if n == 0 then return () else loop (n - 1)
```

Also note that you don't need `0 == n` in Haskell, as there is no way to accidentally use assignment instead of equality comparison (it doesn't compile).

Edit: As the other answers pointed out, `loop` isn't really doing anything - it only calls itself n-1 times and then returns ().

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your intent correctly, you meant to create a "loop" construct that would perform an action *n* times, and produce a list of the results. In the code you have,

```
loop number
xs <- sequence [readLn :: IO Int]
```

But these two statements are separate; you need to instead *send* the action you wish to be repeated *to the `loop`* as inut:

```
xs <- loop number readLn :: IO [Int]
```

Now of course you need to rewrite your `loop` to accept an action as a parameter

```
loop :: Int -> IO a -> IO [a]
loop 0 action = return []  -- don't perform the action
loop n action = do
  x <- action              -- perform the action once
  xs <- loop (n-1) action  -- then perform it (n-1) times
  return (x:xs)            -- produce the resultant list
```

Here I've written it with pattern matching, instead of `if n == 0`. I could just as easily write it with an "if" construct, but I personally tend to find those rather ugly.

But wait, maybe something like this already exists in the standard libraries. Stop...Hoogle time! Hoogling the type signature for our new `loop`, [a -> IO a -> IO [a]](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Int+-%3E+IO+a+-%3E+IO+%5Ba%5D), we discover `replicateM`.

```
xs <- replicateM number readLn :: IO [Int]
```